# Makefile split name by token

Tags: linux, makefile

I need to get a token from the name of current directory, but I want to split it by name.. so say if I have
/home/test/one_two_three
or
/home/test/two

at both cases I'd like to get the 'two' only, i.e. chop everything before after and including '_'

so far I have

```
result=$(notdir ${PWD})
```

but how do I then split it?

Thx!

Comment: Your requirements are not well defined.  What if there is only one `_`: `/home/test/three_four`?  What if there is more than two `_`: `/home/test/five_six_seven_eight`?

Comment: at three_four, I'd want four, there cannot be five_six_seven_eight